# Can't edit the .bashrc file in a container from the "docker exec" command?

Tags: bash, docker, privileges

I am trying to modify the .bashrc file in my container via the:

```
docker exec  -it --workdir /root --user root container_name bash -c "echo 'test' >> /root/.bashrc"
```

Elsewhere in the `/var/www` path it works but not in `/root`.

I checked the rights of the file created in and modified in `/var/www` and it does belong to root:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root      0 Dec 21 10:58 test.txt
```

my intention is simply to add the following lines:

```
export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
eval "$(dircolors)"
alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lA'
```

in file `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Anything you do in an interactive shell like this will be lost as soon as the container exits.  I'd suggest minimizing the amount of time you spend in `docker exec` shells; it's an extremely useful debugging tool, but it's not the normal way you interact with the single process running in a container.  (Why are you spending so much time in a disposable debugging environment that you need to customize its shell?)

Comment: Add the lines in a Dockerfile when building the container.